Is it a bad practice to use Fluent Validation with GET request that has body request?
I am attempting to use Fluent Validator in my project. Most of the tutorials that I come so far is using with a post request where you have a json body as a object and that object will be validated by Fluent Validator.
However, what if I want to use Fluent Validator for a GET request ? Does that GET request need to have a json body ? If so, would it be considered a bad practice for a GET to have a body ?
For ex: Below is an example. I would like to validate the start and end year first before allowing the execution. How would I do that with Fluent Validator ?
Thank you
[HttpGet("preview/secured", Name = nameof(GetPreviewSecuredTaxBillData))]
public IActionResult GetPreviewSecuredTaxBillData([FromQuery] int start, [FromQuery] int end, [FromQuery] string skip, [FromQuery] int pageNumber, [FromQuery] int pageSize)
{
    var taxBills = securedTaxBillService.GetSecuredTaxBills(pageNumber, pageSize);
    return Ok(taxBills);
}


FluentValidation is typically used to evaluate objects, not individual variables. Meaning, instead of having a collection of loosely related variables like start, end, skip, pageNumber, and pageSize, you would instead create an object like TaxBillPageRequest with properties Start, End, Skip, PageNumber, and PageSize and then validate that TaxBillPageRequest  object. And that has nothing to do with GET or POST, as FluentValidation is for validating data and is not concerned with which HTTP Verb was used.

so it is Ok to have an api looks like this ?
[HttpPost("preview/secured", Name = nameof(GetPreviewSecuredTaxBillData))]
public IActionResult GetPreviewSecuredTaxBillData([FromBody] PreviewSecuredTaxBill bill)
{
}


Why would you think that's not okay?

Sorry, I think I meant to say this: (GET instead of POST)
[HttpGet("preview/secured", Name = nameof(GetPreviewSecuredTaxBillData))] public IActionResult GetPreviewSecuredTaxBillData([FromBody] PreviewSecuredTaxBill bill) { }

Again - why would you think it's not okay? I already pointed out that FluentValidation doesn't care whether the object it's validating arrives via a GET or POST request. FluentValidation is a library that validates objects. It's got nothing to do with HTTP.

I do understand that it has nothing to do with FluentValidation. It doesn't care about the HTTP Verb. What I am asking is whether the API looks a bit weird because it has a body request even though it is a GET request according to this discussion link

That'd be an entirely different question. Generally GET requests don't have bodies. I believe you can use a query string and still have the model binder map it to a complex object as your action method's parameter. Try that out.

Why not use a Post?  Many of the old reasons for using get/put/...  are old hat.  Personally I use posts for everything.  In this case I post a ListAPIRequest value object containing the paging. filtering and sorting data.  The API returns a  ListResult.

GET vs all other verbs, is mostly about whether you want back button/bookmarks to include the query values, and whether logs would reveal sensitive information.  It's also relevant when it comes to "state changing"... meaning if the request modifies DB records or other stored state in any way it should not be a GET.  (that's for security issues like CSRF)  IMO, it's just weird to have data in body of a GET request or query vars in non-GET, but I do see a lot of people doing that for some reason.

In general, no reason to avoid validation in GET request as a common rule. FluentValidation is enough fast to do it's work in GET without response time surprises end user.
General case is to response with only valid data from some internal source (DB for example). Or bind some parameters to model object, then validate it. Typically you create OR resolve Or force work in ASP.NET lifecycle your validator object, use it over model object and return according results.

How to bind query to model
How to resolve validator in your controller (example)

Hope it help you.
